# Linear programming optimization problems in finance

Tags: finance, optimization, models, technical-analysis, nonlinear

I'd like to know what are, if any, the applications of linear/non linear programming optimization techniques for financial markets.

I'm a business major, and I want to find an argument for my thesis that unites these techniques with technical analysis for investments on futures, CFD, leverage certificates, commodities (i.e. to say Fibonacci retracements, candlesticks, Elliott waves etc.).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This does not seem to focus on statistics or machine learning. Consider moving this to Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange instead. Regarding the actual question, portfolio optimization requires linear and/or nonlinear programming. E.g. minimize expected shortfall given a target expected return.

Comment: This question has now been migrated but please don't crosspost. As you see it just causes extra work for the moderators.

Comment: Portfolio optimization would be the first place to look. That should have been covered (at least the basics) in intro investments.

Comment: Another, more niche, application is derivatives super-replication.

Comment: @noob2 Could you show me any links or papers about it?

Comment: google super replication linear programming

Comment: @noob2 Thank you!

Comment: You could also consider the different models for portfolio optimization (MAD, MinMax, etc.). They are rather simple and you could start here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/300787539_Linear_Models_for_Portfolio_Optimization